# Working from command line but not with php exec()

Tags: php, cutycapt

I installed [**cutycapt**](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) as root user
I tried it from command prompt

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" /root/cutycapt/CutyCapt/CutyCapt --url=http://www.poochh.com --out=/tmp/example.png
```

But when I am executing it from php `exec()`
I am getting this error on `var_dump($output);` of `exec()`

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(80) "/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 166: /root/cutycapt/CutyCapt/CutyCapt: Permission denied" }
```

Comment: Hi wazzy - Suggest that you ask a second question on how to change permissions of the php user nobody

Comment: Actually installed cutycapt as nobody user and it is working fine now.....Thanks very much for the help...

Comment: Add that as an answer so others can find it!  Thanks for the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the user php runs as!  You may need to make sure it has rights to run cutycapt

Try running

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

to check who php is running as

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...But How to check that

Comment: @Wazzy Try running `echo exec('whoami');` to see who PHP is running as. [Exec - PHP.net](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)